# MSBuild Working with ItemGroup and EXEC Command

Tags: msbuild, command, exec

I created the ItemGroup shown in the code snippet.  I need to iterate through this ItemGroup and run the EXEC command - also shown in the code snippet.  I cannot seem to get it to work.  The code returns the error shown below (note - the Message is written 2 times, which is correct), but the EXEC Command is not running correctly.  The value is not being set; therefore the EXEC is not executing at all.  I need the EXEC to execute twice or by however sections I define in the ItemGroup.

ERROR:
Encrypting WebServer appSettings section
Encrypting WebServer connectionStrings section
C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_regiis.exe -pef "" "\gaw\UI" -prov "RSACustomProvider"
Encrypting configuration section...
The configuration section '' was not found.

CODE SNIPPET:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <SectionsToEncrypt Include="Item">
      <Section>appSettings</Section>     
    </SectionsToEncrypt>
    <SectionsToEncrypt Include="Item">     
      <Section>connectionStrings</Section>
    </SectionsToEncrypt>  
  </ItemGroup>

  <Target Name="EncryptWebServerWebConfigSections">   
    <Message Text="Encrypting WebServer %(SectionsToEncrypt.Section) section" />

    <Exec Command="$(AspNetRegIis) -pef &quot;%(SectionsToEncrypt.Section)&quot; &quot;$(DropLocation)\$(BuildNumber)\%(ConfigurationToBuild.FlavorToBuild)\$(AnythingPastFlavorToBuild)&quot; -prov &quot;$(WebSiteRSACustomProviderName)&quot;"/>
  </Target>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that you are batching on 2 items at a time. What I mean is the you have the statements

```
%(SectionsToEncrypt.Section)
%(ConfigurationToBuild.FlavorToBuild)
```

In the same task invocation. When you batch on more than 1 item at a time in the same task invocation, they will be batch independently. That's why you're error is stating The configuration section **''** ...

If you your FlavorToBuild just has one value what you should do is to stuff that into a property before you call to Exec and then use the property. So your one liner would then convert to:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <_FlavToBuild>%(ConfigurationToBuild.FlavorToBuild)<_FlavToBuild>
</PropertyGroup>
<Exec Command="$(AspNetRegIis) -pef &quot;%(SectionsToEncrypt.Section)&quot; &quot;$(DropLocation)\$(BuildNumber)\$(_FlavToBuild)\$(AnythingPastFlavorToBuild)&quot; -prov &quot;$(WebSiteRSACustomProviderName)&quot;"/>
```

If you have multiple values for FlavorToBuild then it's more complicated. You would have 2 options:

1. Hard code Exec more than once
2. Use target batching with task batching to perform the foreach/foreach

Batching is one of the most confusing elements of MSBuild. I've put together some online resources at http://sedotech.com/Resources#batching. If you want to know more than that then you can pick up a copy of my [book](http://sedotech.com/Resources/InsideMSBuildBook).

Comment: +1 And can highly recommend the book - replaces weeks of "aha, so that's waht I didnt get" with a proper top to bottom tour.

Comment: Yes +1 on the book recommendation :)