# Why do these MSBuild Output Items seem empty, when they are not?

Tags: msbuild, msbuild-task

Strange way to put a question, anyway ... Basically this is my first real attempt with MSBuild.

I managed to create a Target (*RenameJs*) which produces a new Output Items List named *JsMinifyOutput* (a renamed version of another input list).

Then, in a dependent Target (*ClosureCompile*) I'm trying to actually use the previously generated Output list. I have a Message Task as the following, where I can see the Output List values printed on the console:

```xml
    <Message Text="Outputs: %(JsMinifyOutput.FullPath)" />
```

But then, in the same dependent Target, when I try to use the Output List in the *actual* Exec Task, the list seems to be empty. The following task:

```xml
<Exec Command="$(ClosureCompilerCmd) --js %(JsMinify.FullPath) --js_output_file %(JsMinifyOutput.FullPath)" />
```

appears on the console as just:

```
java -jar Some\Path\To\SomeInputFile.debug.js --js_output_file
```

while I would expect something like:

```
java -jar Some\Path\To\SomeInputFile.js --js_output_file Some\Path\To\SomeFileRenamed.js
```

If I try with this simple Exec Task, it properly shows all file names:

```
<Exec Command="echo %(JsMinifyOutput.FullPath)" />
```

What I am trying to achieve here is the following: starting from an input ItemGroup list, create another (output) ItemGroup list by means of some transformation over the former (e.g. renaming, replacing text, ...). Then, having this two ItemGroup lists, loop over them *in parallel* so to say, and perform an Exec task over them. In pseudo-language, something like:

```
 for(i from 0 to inList.length)
 {
   Exec Command="Path\To\Some\Command --in inList[i] --out outList[i]
 }
```

Am I doing something completely silly here? 
PS: This is with Build Engine Version 4.0, .NET Framework Version 4.0

Comment: might depend on what's in the 'omitted' part: is it references another list with a % sign it might screw up things

Comment: yes, it references another list with '%', coming from an ItemGroup. Does that cause problems? BTW, I edited the question to remove the omitted part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uhm, it seems that Exec Task cannot iterate over two *parallel* ItemGroups at the same time. ... At least that is what a MSBuild guru answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2761967/msbuild-working-with-itemgroup-and-exec-command):

> The problem is that you are batching on 2 items at a time.

<strike>I'm not totally sure if</strike> what I'm trying to do here is "batching on 2 items at a time".

**EDIT**

Having cleared what's the actual reason for the task not working, here's my approach to (what I think is) a clean solution:

1. Add a new *metadata* to the existing input `ItemGroup`. That metadata  **is** the calculated output path and takes the place of the former output ItemGroup. Inside the metadata you find the filepath transformation (rename, replace, ...) achieved somehow (through *Inline Task*, *Property Function*, *Transform*, you name it).
2. Reference the new metadata where the former output ItemGroup was used, e.g. within `Exec Command` attribute, or within the `Target Outputs` attribute.

By way of an example:

```
<Target Name="JsRename"> <!-- This adds the metadata -->
  <ItemGroup>
    <JsMinify>
      <OutputPath>[do something over %(FullPath)</OutputPath>
    </JsMinify>
  </ItemGroup>
</Target>
<Target Name="ClosureCompile" DependsOnTargets="JsRename"> <!-- Here is the actual task -->
  <Exec Command="$(ClosureCompilerCmd) --js %(JsMinify.FullPath) --js_output_file %(JsMinify.OutputPath)" />
</Target>
```

Comment: that's definitely not only with Exec, but rather with all tasks.

Answer (score 0):

From my (limited) experience with msbuild, it seems that you cannot use two lists like that. Just put the same in the Message task and you'll see what's it doing.

You can use one list with metadata though, which just requires you to generate the cross-product manually from the two other lists:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <JsMinify Include="a"/>
  <JsMinify Include="b"/>
  <JsMinifyOutput Include="d"/>
  <JsMinifyOutput Include="e"/>
</ItemGroup>

<Target Name="CrossProduct">
  <ItemGroup>
    <InPath Include="@(JsMinify->'%(Identity)')">
      <OutPath>%(JsMinifyOutput.Identity)</OutPath>
    </InPath>
  </ItemGroup>
</Target>

<Target Name="Show" DependsOnTargets="CrossProduct">
  <Message Text="%(InPath.Identity) and %(InPath.OutPath)"/>
</Target>
```

running this will output

```
  a and d
  b and d
  a and e
  b and e
```

**Update**
There are multiple way batching can be done; here's a slightly different in which you also have to add metadata but in another way; in fact, following your loop pseudo-code, the JsGroup I used below corresponds to the loop counter. While this sample seems to do what you are after, I unfortunately do not know an automatic way to generate the numbers so it's not really a solution but I'll post it anyway as it's interesting enough.

```
<ItemGroup>
  <JsMinify Include="a">
    <JsGroup>1</JsGroup>
  </JsMinify>
  <JsMinify Include="b">
    <JsGroup>2</JsGroup>
  </JsMinify>

  <JsMinifyOutput Include="d">
    <JsGroup>1</JsGroup>
  </JsMinifyOutput>
  <JsMinifyOutput Include="e">
    <JsGroup>2</JsGroup>
  </JsMinifyOutput>
</ItemGroup>

<Message Text="%(JsGroup): @(JsMinify) and @(JsMinifyOutput)"/>
```

Outputs

```
a and d
b and e
```

I looked further and since you are using msbuild 4, a whole new world of possibilities opens. Using the same ItemGroup and above, here's an inline task that calls your loop in real code:

```
<UsingTask TaskName="LoopBoth" TaskFactory="CodeTaskFactory" AssemblyFile="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.Build.Tasks.v4.0.dll">
  <ParameterGroup>
    <JsMinify ParameterType="System.String[]" Required="true" />
    <JsMinifyOutput ParameterType="System.String[]" Required="true" />
  </ParameterGroup>
  <Task>
    <Code Type="Fragment" Language="cs">
      <![CDATA[
          for( int i = 0 ; i < JsMinify.Length ; ++i )
          {
            Log.LogMessage( JsMinify[ i ] + " and " + JsMinifyOutput[ i ] );
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start( "java",
              "-jar " + JsMinify[ i ] + " --js_output_file " + JsMinifyOutput[ i ] );
          }
      ]]>
    </Code>
  </Task>
</UsingTask>

<Target Name="DoIt">
  <LoopBoth JsMinify="@(JsMinify)" JsMinifyOutput="@(JsMinifyOutput)"/>
</Target>
```

You could off course extend this and pass just JsMinify and do the transformation within the task.

Comment: interesting way to use ItemGroups. But I actually do _not_ want the cross product. I'd like instead to process items _in parallel_, e.g. run the task for each couple of items in JsMinify and JsMinifyOutput.

Comment: can you elaborate? With parallel, do you mean 'at the same time'? In that case, Exec doesn't do that afaik, but you could resort to calling the msbuild task on multiple project files at the same time, since the msbuild task can run in parallel. But even then I think you'd still need to build this cross-product somewhere.

Comment: please have a look at my edited question. And BTW, thanks for you time.

Comment: I've come to a solution too, and I'll post it here too as a reference. Yes I played with v4.0 Inline Tasks, as well as with Property functions and ItemGroup Metadata. I do not _strictly_ have or need an index, or a loop, and as you noticed that's just pseudo code. Not sure now which is THE answer :)